# How to grep out binary name from windows file path

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to extract the actual binary name (*.exe) from a fully qualified Windows path. So, I have a file with lines containing strings similar to:

```
"c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe"
```

How can I extract the very last part of the path, the exe name?

I've tried to use `grep -Eo "\\\(.*).exe"` , but since there are backslashes in the earlier part of the path, it goes all the way up until it can't see a backslash anymore.

Comment: Are the paths all surrounded by double quotes?  Are they all .exe files/are you only looking for exe files?  Is there any lines in the file other than the paths?

Comment: Yes they are all surrounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greedily delete everything up to the last backslash and keep what comes after that, up to the quote character:

```
sed 's/.*\\\(.*\)"/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk (assuming there are no other lines in the file):

```
awk -F'\' '{gsub(/"/, ""); print $NF}' file.txt
```

awk will use `\` as the field separator, gsub() will remove the double quote, and then it will print the last field (the filename).

If this file contains more than just .exe files and you only want to see .exe files you can use:

```
awk -F'\' '/exe"$/{gsub(/"/, ""); print $NF}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
echo '"c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe"' | rev | cut -d'\' -f1 | rev | sed 's,"$,,'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
$ echo '"c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe"' | grep -Eo '[^\\]+\.exe'
rundll32.exe
```

This matches and prints one-or-more characters that **aren't** a backslash `[^\\]+` followed immediately by `\.exe`.